# tikz-cd quiver code not working

Tags: diagrams, texlive, overleaf, tikz-cd

The [quiver gives me the following code](https://q.uiver.app/?q=WzAsNSxbMCwyLCJcXG1hdGhiYntafV80XnsoMSl9IFxcdGV4dHsgc3Vic3lzdGVtfVxcXFwgXFx0ZXh0e2NvZGV9Il0sWzAsM10sWzAsMCwiXFxtYXRoYmJ7Wn1fNCBcXHRleHR7IHRvcmljIGNvZGV9Il0sWzIsMiwiXFx0ZXh0e0NoaXJhbCBzZW1pb259IFxcXFwgXFx0ZXh0e3N1YnN5c3RlbSBjb2RlfSJdLFsyLDAsIlxcdGV4dHtEb3VibGUgc2VtaW9ufSBcXFxcIFxcdGV4dHtzdGFiaWxpemVyIGNvZGV9Il0sWzIsMCwiXFxmb290bm90ZXNpemUgXFx0ZXh0e0dhdWdlfVxcdGV4dHsgYXdheSB9ZV4zbSIsMl0sWzAsMywiXFxmb290bm90ZXNpemVcXHRleHR7Q29uZGVuc2UgfXNeMiIsMl0sWzIsNCwiXFxmb290bm90ZXNpemUgXFx0ZXh0e0NvbmRlbnNlIH0gZV4ybV4yIiwyXSxbNCwzLCJcXGZvb3Rub3Rlc2l6ZVxcdGV4dHtHYXVnZSBhd2F5IH1cXGJhcntzfSAiXV0=)

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,row sep=scriptsize]
    {\mathbb{Z}_2 \text{ A}} \&\& {\text{A} \\ \text{B}} \\
    \\
    {\mathbb{Z}_4 \text{ A }\\ \text{B}} \&\& {\alpha \\ \text{DG}} \\
    {}
    \arrow["{\footnotesize \beta}"', from=1-1, to=3-1]
    \arrow["\footnotesize\epsilon"', from=3-1, to=3-3]
    \arrow["{\footnotesize \chi}"', from=1-1, to=1-3]
    \arrow["\footnotesize\gamma", from=1-3, to=3-3]
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

for the following output

[image]

but this does not work in my local texlive compiler or on overleaf. Note that I did download quiver.sty and use \usepackage{quiver} in the preamble. What is the right syntax to get exactly the above placement of symbols and text?

Comment: Where did you get `quiver.sty`? I didn't find it at their site.

Comment: Click on LaTex at the bottom of the webpage I linked and you will find the link to quiver.sty at the top. This is the link btw https://raw.githubusercontent.com/varkor/quiver/master/src/quiver.sty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but the software you're using produces wrong code for the stacked entries and overly complicated code in general.

Just practice a little and writing commutative diagrams by yourself will become easy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\cdstack}[2]{\begin{matrix}#1\\#2\end{matrix}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
  \mathbb{Z}_2\;\mathrm{A} \arrow[r,"\chi"'] \arrow[d,"\beta"'] &
  \cdstack{\mathrm{A}}{\mathrm{B}} \arrow[d,"\gamma"] \\
  \cdstack{\mathbb{Z}_4\;\mathrm{A}}{\mathrm{B}} \arrow[r,"\epsilon"'] &
  \cdstack{\alpha}{\mathrm{DG}}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\text` is not the right command for this job, if you really want the letters to be upright. Probably `huge` is too big, here's the output with `large` instead.

[image]

You may want to adjust the position of the label `\gamma`, which by default is placed in the middle of the arrow and `pos=0.35` seems to be right. In order to cover our tracks we might lower a bit the label `\beta`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\cdstack}[2]{\begin{matrix}#1\\#2\end{matrix}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
  \mathbb{Z}_2\;\mathrm{A} \arrow[r,"\chi"'] \arrow[d,pos=0.55,"\beta"'] &
  \cdstack{\mathrm{A}}{\mathrm{B}} \arrow[d,pos=0.40,"\gamma"] \\
  \cdstack{\mathbb{Z}_4\;\mathrm{A}}{\mathrm{B}} \arrow[r,"\epsilon"'] &
  \cdstack{\alpha}{\mathrm{DG}}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- Apparently quiver doesn't generate useful code. It contains errors.
- Rewriting your code fragment and extending it to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
 \tikzcdset{
    every label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
    cells={nodes={align=center}}
            }
   \begin{tikzcd}[sep=5em]    
$\mathbb{Z}_2$ A \dar["\beta" '] \rar["\chi"]
                &   \makecell{A\\ B} \dar["\gamma"] \\
\makecell{$\mathbb{Z}_4$ A \\ B} \rar["\epsilon"'] 
                &   \makecell{$\alpha$\\ DG}        \\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

works fine. It gives the following result:

[image]

In above MWE I made the following changes:

- use `makecell` for cells with two lines text
- math content in `makecell` had to be encapsulated with `$`
- arrows are moved to cells of commutative diagram
- styles of cells and size of the edge labels are defined by `\tikzcdset`

Answer (score 3):

Now, that people told you

- not to use Quiver and
- to write directly TikZ-CD

here's a way to not have to deal with extra macros inside the cells.

The keys `math align=center|left|right` and `text align=center|left|right` might be helpful for that.
Caveat: you need to put your whole cell content in `{}` but you need to specify that alignment in the options to the `tikzcd` environment. It's to late for that inside the cell. It also doesn't allow for a manual node or any `\path` content like the `matrix of [math] nodes` style.

However, it'll allow an optional argment inside `|<opts>|` (without `[]`!) that gets forwarded to the node.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{
  rc/.style 2 args={
    /utils/tempa/.style args={r##1c##2}{/tikz/row ##1 column ##2/.append style={#2}},
    /utils/tempa/.list={#1}}}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  clear/.is choice,
  clear/at begin cell/.code=\let\tikz@atbegin@cell\pgfutil@empty,
  clear/at end cell/.code=\let\tikz@atend@cell\pgfutil@empty,
  @align/.style={
    clear=at begin cell, clear=at end cell,
    execute at begin cell=#1},
  math align/.is choice,
  math align/center/.style={@align=\tikz@grab@cell{\iftikzcd@mathmode\else$\fi}{array}cc},
  math align/left/.style  ={@align=\tikz@grab@cell{\iftikzcd@mathmode\else$\fi}{array}cl},
  math align/right/.style ={@align=\tikz@grab@cell{\iftikzcd@mathmode\else$\fi}{array}cr},
  text align/.is choice,
  text align/center/.style={@align=\tikz@grab@cell{}{tabular}cc},
  text align/left/.style  ={@align=\tikz@grab@cell{}{tabular}cl},
  text align/right/.style ={@align=\tikz@grab@cell{}{tabular}cr},
}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tikz@grab@cell}{m m m m D||{} m }{%
  \node[name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,#5]
    {#1\begin{#2}[#3]{@{}#4@{}}#6\end{#2}};}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[
  sep=large,
  ',
  every label/.append style={node font=\footnotesize},
  rc={r1c2, r2c1, r2c2}{math align=center}]
     \mathbb Z_2 A       \dar["\beta"] \rar["\chi"] &      {A \\ B} \dar["\gamma"'] \\
    {\mathbb Z_4 A \\ B} \rar["\epsilon"]           & |red|{\alpha \\ DG}
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]