# tikzcd: newline in node's content

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I'm trying to add a new line in `tikzcd`'s node, but it fails. Any idea why?

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
This works:
\begin{tikz}
  \node[draw,align=left]{B \\ B};
\end{tikz}
This fails:
\begin{tikzcd}
  |[align=left]|{B \\ B}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Error: `! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.`

Comment: Maybe insert a text width on it?

Comment: @Sigur thanks but it's not working

Comment: Math-mode or text-mode? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/660452

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether there is a more elegant method, but you could nest a `tabular` (if your contents should be in math mode, use `array` instead of `tabular`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
This works:
\begin{tikz}
  \node[draw,align=left]{B \\ B};
\end{tikz}
This fails:
\begin{tikzcd}
  |[align=left]|{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}B \\ B\end{tabular}}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks… but ideally I would love  avoid using tabular. But if there is no other way I guess I'll go for that…

Comment: @tobiasBora well, `\vbox{\hbox{B}\hbox{B}}` avoids `tabular`, but I'm not sure you should prefer that... :P But I have no experience with `tikzcd`, so might very well be that there is some clever thing.

Comment: Ahah yeah, I just meant something that does not require strange workarounds. But I'll accept this for now, thanks

Comment: Why not `array`?

Comment: @egreg because I don't know whether he wants math mode or text mode...